# Bootstrap Datetimepicker JS Format Date Output

Tags: php, jquery, date, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am using  bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js which originally from here (http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

when i click some button, the ajax is returning datetime in this format:

Thu Jul 18 2019 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

how to make this format to yyyy-mm-dd so it can fit in mysql database?

i've see some function inside the js file there is formatDate(d) function. But there's no documentation regarding that function..

**code for getting the result**

```
  var expired_date= $('#dateTimeExpired').data('datetimepicker');
       exp_date = expired_date.getDate();
```

Is there any helps?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dateRaw = "Thu Jul 18 2019 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)";
var dateObject = new Date(dateRaw);
var dateFormatted = dateObject.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

alert(dateFormatted); // 2019-07-18
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eymA4/

Comment: thanks steve. But i've created another function in php to decode that dateRaw. good day